# How can I save enum items in a streamwriter?

Tags: c#, enums, streamwriter

I have a `enum list`(?) and I want to save it in a `StreamWriter`, but I don't know how to save it, what I mean is:

```
TextWriter gPieza = new StreamWriter("Pieza.txt", true);
gPieza.WriteLine();
gPieza.Close();
```

I don't know how to put it in the WriteLine. I tried to put `Class.EnumName.ToString();` but it won't let me, what appears after de EnumName is the different thing that the Enum has.

These are my `enum lists`:

```
    public enum Types
    {
        Vacio,
        Peon,
        Torre,
        Caballo,
        Alfil,
        Reina,
        Rey
    }

    public enum Colors
    {
        White,
        Black
    }
```

These are part of a chess game, I need to save what piece the user put on the checkerboard and in what position the Piece was placed.

```
    Types _type;
    Colors _color;
    Point _coord;
```

Answer (score 1):

For writing just the enum,

```
var myEnums = new List<MyEnum>
                  {
                      MyEnum.Value1,
                      MyEnum.Value2,
                      MyEnum.Value1, 
                      MyEnum.Value1,
                      MyEnum.Value2,
                      MyEnum.Value1, 
                      MyEnum.Value1,
                      MyEnum.Value2,
                      MyEnum.Value1
                  };

var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt");

foreach (var myEnum in myEnums)
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(myEnum);
}

streamWriter.Close();
```

If you want to write the actual values

```
streamWriter.WriteLine((int)myEnum);
```

**Update** 
For writing multiple type of enum you can write some method like,

```
public static void WriteEnums<T>(List<T> enums)
{
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt");

    foreach (var myEnum in enums)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(myEnum);
    }

    streamWriter.Close();
}
```

And call it,

```
var types = new List<Types>
                  {
                      Types.Alfil,
                      Types.Peon,
                      Types.Vacio
                  };

var colorses = new List<Colors>
                   {
                       Colors.Black, Colors.Black, Colors.White
                   };


WriteEnums(colorses);
WriteEnums(types);
```

Comment: And if I have 2 different enums and one point, do I need to create different StreamWriters? (what I mean is that I have type, color and position)

Comment: I edited the question with the code that I have for each piece

Comment: Note, not for all enums basetype is `int`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))) 
{ 
     Console.WriteLine(enumValue); // or enumValue.ToString()
}
```